# Click detection iframe

Tags: javascript

I spend hours to find a solution for click detection inside iframe and the result is, its not possible. We can only detect a shift in focus and all solutions that I could find anywhere do not work on either chrome or Firefox. or only register the first click because the focus can not be bring back programmatically in JavaScript.

I build a solution my self which works in Firefox and google chrome and detects every click. the only thing is it can differentiate between left/right click and I have no way of testing it on safari.

```js
let mouseover = false,
    tab = false;

function registerCLick(elem){
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME' && !tab && mouseover){ // check if activeElement is iframe, not tab key action and mouseover iframe
        console.log(elem.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id'));
    };
    tab = false;
};


document.addEventListener('mousemove', ()=>{ // this sets back the focus to document if the activeElement is iframe
    var elem = document.activeElement;
    if(elem && elem.tagName == 'IFRAME'){
        window.focus();
    };
});


document.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{ // ignore blur by Tab key
    if(e.key == 'Tab'){
        tab = true;
    };
}, false);

window.addEventListener('blur', ()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{ // firefox take a bit longet to change the activeElement, we wait before checking if iframe is the active element
        registerCLick(document.activeElement);
    }, 500);
});

function frameListener(frame){ // eventlistener per iframe to know when hover
    frame.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
        mouseover = true;
    }); 

    frame.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            mouseover = false;
        }, 1000);
    });
};

frameListener(iframe); // call function for each iframe with iframe element as parameter
```

I have not tested it on mobile browsers, if someone has time to check on mobile device and or safari. we might could build a solution that works good enough.

My question is, how can I make this better? make it differentiate between left/right click? and is there someone that could test it on safari?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: its a solution that is no where to be found

Comment: That's not a question. StackOverflow is about answering questions. It's hard to answer when we don't know what is being asked

Comment: Then why not re-write it is actually a propper question?  "How can I make this better?" is not a propper question. As it stands, this is not a good fit for StackOverflow. I've voted to close but not down voted. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to get a better idea of what is expected.

Comment: I added a question at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

I usually wrap the iframe on div and use event listeners on this div.

```
<div class='test'>
<iframe src="url" title="description"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: just wrapping iframe inside a div won't give you a click event